# Manjaro не устанавливается

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro

С помощью etcher на ubuntu загрузил на флешку manjaro 18 kde. Размечал диск так:
GPT
8 gb - /boot,флаги esp
100gb - / ,флаги корневой
200gb - /home, флагов нет.
Везде ext4.
Пишет,что установка завершена,однако boot from selected device are failed. При попытки поставить в загрузку /boot/efi,выводит ошибку. Подскажите,что делать.
Запасной флешки нет. Ненужного компа нет. При установке а-ля erase disk тоже boot from selected device are failed

Comment: Как был создан образ?

Answer (score 0):

esp должна быть fat32, а не ext4.